# Too many passes with Drupal 7 test framework

Tags: testing

I'm implementing some tests using the D7 testing framework.

All is good, except that the numbers don't seem to add up, and I wondered how pass/fail was evaluated?

The problem is that I'm getting "6 passes, 0 fails, 4 exceptions, and 2 debug messages" for two test methods.

Obviously I'm missing something, but I had assumed that a single test method would produce a single pass/fail and therefore I should only have two results.

Secondly, how can I find out more information about the exceptions that were reported?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `assert()`ion you have in your test code will result in a pass, fail or even an exception.  The uncaught exceptions are bad fails.

If you're running your tests with `scripts/run-tests.sh`, then use the `--verbose` flag and you'll be able to see the result of each assertion and any associated error/s.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that makes sense.

I'd vote up, but it seems I need more rep.

Answer (score 2):

Many, many internal methods run asserts, even `setup`. Almost all drupal* methods do, for example, `drupalCreateUser`, `drupalCreateUser`, `drupalLogin`, `drupalGet'`drupalPost`.